# Can't edit partitions with Disk Utility in OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I'm having trouble accessing about 50GB of space on my computer after a failed partitioning attempt. Before you ask, I don't know what went wrong, I just know that now, I can only turn the free space into an additional partition. I really just want to be able to resize or edit the partition map, but Disk Utility has other plans in mind. Suggestions? I'm sure I'm not the first person to see something like this.

[image]

Comment: @Please add a complete screenshot of Disk Utility (including the left pane). Probably you have CoreStorage volume and you have to boot from different disk and use the `diskutil cs resizeStack`command in Terminal to expand your main volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out myself. All I had to do was turn off FileVault and restart the system. Disk Utility works normally now.

Comment: Good that you found a solution to your issue. Please mark this as your answer if it solved your question.